# Repeated Recurrence Substitution

Tags: algorithms

T(n) = n + 2 * T((n − 1) / 2)

- Where n = 2^k - 1

I got to step i but I don't know how to get the general step i.

- Step 0: T(2^k - 1) = 2^k - 1 + 2T (2^k - 2)
- Step 1: T(2^k - 1) = 2^k - 1 + 2^k - 2 + 4T(2^k-2 - 1)
- Step 2: T(2^k - 1) = 2^k - 1 + 2^k - 2 + 2^k - 4 + 8T(2^k-3 -1)
- What I got for step i was: (2^k - 2^i) + 2^i+1 (2^k-i-1 - 1)

I know that's not right though because it does not gather all the terms for each step. It only gathers the last last 2 terms. Can someone help me with step i please? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to divide by $2$. For $n = 2^k-1$, we have:

\begin{align*}
T(2^k - 1) &= T(n) = n + 2T((n-1)/2) = 2^k - 1 + 2T((2^k-1-1)/2) \\
&= 2^k - 1 + 2T(2^{k-1}-1).
\end{align*}

By the way, you're missing the terminating case, $k=0$.

The general solution seems to be

$$T(2^k - 1) = 2^k (k - 1 + T(0)) + 1.\tag{*}$$

We prove the formula $(*)$ using the [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

The basis of the induction is easy to check, either for $k = 0$, or for $k = 1$. We assume that the formula $(*)$ is good for $k-1$, i.e., we assume that

$$T(2^{k-1} - 1) = 2^{k-1} ((k-1) - 1 + T(0)) + 1. \tag{**}$$

We check for $k$:

\begin{align*}
T(2^k-1) &= \text{use the definition of $T(2^k-1)$} \\
&= 2^k-1 + 2 T((2^k - 1 − 1) / 2) = 2^k-1 + 2 T(2^{k-1} - 1) \\
&= \text{use $(**)$} \\
&= 2^k-1 + 2 \left( 2^{k-1} ((k-1) - 1 + T(0)) + 1 \right) \\
&= 2^k-1 + 2^k ((k-1) - 1 + T(0)) + 2 \\
&= 2^k (1 + (k-1) - 1 + T(0)) + 1 \\
&= 2^k (k - 1 + T(0)) + 1,
\end{align*}

which completes the proof of formula $(*)$.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it wrong. I had that in Step 0.

I am still confused about the step i though, I don't know what the general solution is.

 I know that the 2^i+1 (2^k-i-1 - 1) is right though because that will get the correct T(n) for each step , but I don't know how to find a general solution to get each of the terms before that in each step. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @user101985 I have added what seems to be the solution. Try to prove it using the [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Comment: I dont think that is correct because in this case, T(1) = 1.

Also , please try to look at my step i because 2^i+1 (2^k-i-1 - 1) in that step is correct, as you can test is with i = 0, 1, or 2. You will see that you get the same T(n) value required in each step . I just don't know how to get the previous steps before it.

Comment: @user101985 $T(1) = 1 + 2T((1-1)/2)) = 1 + T(0)$. So, if $T(0) = 0$, then my solution gives the correct value. If $T(0) \ne 0$, you need to say what it is. As for your step, please edit your post and try to make it clear(er), possibly by using [the proper notation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I can't understand how $i$ fits in the **final** solution, when there are no more recursive calls. I have to leave now, but I'll check this out when I get back (in a few hours).

Comment: T(0) is not given. Only T(1) = 1.

Comment: @user101985 Well, put $T(0) = 0$ in my formula, and you get $T(1) = 1$. So, $T(2^k-1) = 2^k(k-1)+1$.

Comment: @user101985 I've edited my answer to include the proof of the previously proposed solution.